# Strange keyboard behaviour "k" not available under dwm except dmenu

Tags: xorg, keyboard, locale, dwm, openrc

I'm using a german standard keyboard (*Cherry KC 1000*, qwertz, with ä, ö, ü, etc.) set to `us` layout and installed an `artix linux (openrc)` system from scratch manually and seemingly something very strange happens in `dwm`. When I press **`k`** on the keyboard **nothing happens**. However, when I use it for searching in `dmenu` it works fine. And if I exit from dwm -- on terminal -- it works again!

I've tested some settings -- see below --, but the *no `k` behavior* remains persistent.

```
setxkbmap -model pc105 layout us -variant, querty
setxkbmap -model pc105 layout de -variant, querty
setxkbmap -model pc105 layout us -variant, quertz
setxkbmap -model pc105 layout de -variant, quertz

setxkbmap -model pc104 layout us -variant, querty
setxkbmap -model pc104 layout de -variant, querty
setxkbmap -model pc104 layout us -variant, quertz
setxkbmap -model pc104 layout de -variant, quertz
```

When using `xinput` the keyboard is detected as `Cherry USB keyboard`.
Testing with the corespondent id `xinput test 11` the key press is detected as `key press 45`.

Any Idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It had to do with a wrong setting in `dwm`s `config.h` file where I've mapped the `107` key to do a print screen. Now I've commented out the line, recompiled, and `k` works again. However it seems strange since `k` is mapped on `45`, not  `107`.

If you have an idea why this happend, I would be very thankful if you comment this answer. Best wishes!